# Change Libreoffice Impress screen background color

Tags: libreoffice

[image: Change Libreoffice Impress screen background color]

I would like to change the black background to white.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change this. The black bars are an indication that the slide isn't exactly the same resolution ratio as the screen, thus producing (in your case) the black side bars. In my case (see [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EEAn2TjKEAeVVVb2d5LUk0S2c/edit?usp=sharing)) these bars line the top and bottom.

Comment: Oh! so I would need to figure out the resolution of the projector I will be giving this presentation with, right?

Comment: Yes, that should help.